# Marketing Cloud SOAP API - How to change a Subscribers status back to Active?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

My use case is this:

If a customer hit's the unsubscribe button, we perform a SOAP Callout to Marketing Cloud to log an UnsubEvent.  Which works great.

Now if the our customer hits the button by mistake, or wishes to opt-back in for other purposes we want to reactivate that subscriber in Marketing Cloud.  My understanding is that this is possible with an update call.

Here's my envelope.  This is all being done via Snaplogic.

```
<Envelope
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Header>
        <wsse:Security mustUnderstand="1"
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>">******************</</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">">******************</</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <UpdateRequest
            xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Options>
                <SaveOptions>
                    <SaveOption>
                        <PropertyName>*</PropertyName>
                        <SaveAction>UpdateOnly</SaveAction>
                    </SaveOption>
                </SaveOptions>
            </Options>
            <Objects type="Subscriber">
                <PartnerKey nil="true" />
                <ObjectID nil="true" />
                <EmailAddress>">******************</</EmailAddress>
                <Status>Active</Status>
                <SubscriberKey>">******************</</SubscriberKey>
            </Objects>
        </UpdateRequest>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

And the response I get is:

```
"ExecuteResponseMsg":
{
"@xmlns":
http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI
"OverallStatus":
OK
"RequestID":
5da36253-fcb6-423b-b652-cc2d7b58a407
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a different approach, updated the all subscribers list and included the status attribute as part of the list.  This worked correctly.

```
    <UpdateRequest
        xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
            <SubscriberKey>***************</SubscriberKey>
            <Lists>
                <ID>****</ID>
                <Status>Active</Status>
                <Action>Update</Action>
            </Lists>
        </Objects>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this envelope but adjust the authentication in the header -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Update</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">{{https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx}}</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{AuthToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
                <SubscriberKey>{{SubscriberKey}}</SubscriberKey>
                    <Status>Active</Status>
                    <Action>Update</Action>
            </Objects>
        </UpdateRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```